# Self invoking anonymous functions

Tags: javascript, d3.js, self-invoking-function

I am trying to understand the following example of d3.js:
http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/3884955

In the example there are a lot of lines of code that looks like this:

```
data.forEach(function(d) {
    d.date = parseDate(d.date);
});
```

or

```
x.domain(d3.extent(data, function(d) { return d.date; }));
```

But I can't figure out, where d gets passed as an argument and what d is? How does this "magic" work?

Comment: it's not Self invoking anonymous functions, it's just anonymous functions, passed as arguments

Comment: `forEach` uses a callback that processes each element in the array. `d` is the current element in the cycle. `d` can be called anything btw. I'm guessing `extent` is a method that takes an array (`data`) and uses a callback in a similar way. In each example, `d` appears to be an array of JavaScript objects.

Answer (score 2):

In the first snippet, `d` is an element of the array `data`. The anonymous function given as the second argument to `.forEach()` is executed for each element of the array `data` and parses the `.date` attribute of the datum.

In the second case, the anonymous function in the second argument to `d3.extent()` tells D3 how to extract the value to use to compute the extent from `data`. That is, each element of `data` is considered to compute the extent of values in the array, but the elements may also be complex objects instead of simple numbers. For numbers, no second argument (access function) is required, but for objects (as in this case), you need to tell D3 what value to consider -- `.date` here.

So in both cases, the anonymous functions are applied to each element in the array `data` and the argument `d` that is passed to them is the respective element of the array. Note that the name `d` is arbitrary here, you could just as well call `d` `element` or `datum` or something like that.

Answer (score 1):

Your callback isn't self-invoking - the function that you call directly (`forEach` or `extent`) calls it.

That function decides when to call your callback, and with what arguments. In the case of `Array.prototype.forEach`, it is executed once for each element of the array. The arguments are the current element and the array index.

For example, a simple `forEach`-style function could look like this:

```
function each(array, callback) {
  for(var i = 0; i < array.length; ++ i) {
    callback(array[i], i);
  }
}
```

Example usage:

```
each([1,2,3], function(element, i) {
  console.log(element * element, i);
})

// Output: 
// 1 0
// 4 1
// 9 2
```

Notice how your callback is executed three times, with different arguments each time. Your callback doesn't control the arguments or how many times it is called - that is under the control of `each`.